# custom keyboard Radio Button Telegram JAVA

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot

I like to this ?, how do I do in JAVA?

source = https://www.mql5.com/es/articles/2355

[image ...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nI7Ec.png)

Comment: I don't get what you are asking. Explenation on how to create the menu linked in your image can be also found in the link you just gave. For clarification: Those radio buttons are merely emojis. ⚪️ and .

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how to make an object in Java but I can provide you an idea on how to do that. As you show in the keyboard, the JSON should be send like this:

```
...
...
'reply_markup': JSON.stringify({
  keyboard: 
    [
      [
        {'text': 'Radio Button #1'}
      ],
      [
        {'text': 'Radio Button #2'}
      ],
      [
        {'text': 'Radio Button #3'}
      ],
      [
        {'text': 'Unlock'},
        {'text': 'Mute'}
      ]
    ],
  one_time_keyboard: true,
  resize_keyboard: true
...
```

You need to send the keyboard JSON like this to show the keyboard as the image. Just search what's the equivalent of JSON.stringify in Java and how to make a request and how to construct an object in that language.

To put an emoji in the keyboard message, you need to search the unicode code of this emoji and write it in the keyboard text, something like this:

```
...
  {'text': '\u{270B} Radio Button #1'},
...
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using [Ruben's library](https://github.com/rubenlagus/TelegramBots)

Here's an example of 9 buttons which will be split into 3 buttons per row

By typing /inline will produce inline keyboard

By typing /keyboard will produce custom keyboard

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.telegram.telegrambots.api.methods.AnswerCallbackQuery;
import org.telegram.telegrambots.api.methods.send.SendMessage;
import org.telegram.telegrambots.api.objects.Message;
import org.telegram.telegrambots.api.objects.Update;
import org.telegram.telegrambots.api.objects.replykeyboard.InlineKeyboardMarkup;
import org.telegram.telegrambots.api.objects.replykeyboard.ReplyKeyboard;
import org.telegram.telegrambots.api.objects.replykeyboard.ReplyKeyboardMarkup;
import org.telegram.telegrambots.api.objects.replykeyboard.buttons.InlineKeyboardButton;
import org.telegram.telegrambots.api.objects.replykeyboard.buttons.KeyboardButton;
import org.telegram.telegrambots.api.objects.replykeyboard.buttons.KeyboardRow;
import org.telegram.telegrambots.bots.TelegramLongPollingBot;
import org.telegram.telegrambots.exceptions.TelegramApiException;

/**
 * @author UnAfraid
 */
public class MyBot extends TelegramLongPollingBot
{
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyBot.class);

    private final String _token;
    private final String _username;

    public MyBot(String token, String username)
    {
        _token = token;
        _username = username;
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpdateReceived(Update update)
    {
        if (update.hasMessage() && update.getMessage().hasText())
        {
            final Message message = update.getMessage();
            ReplyKeyboard markup = null;
            if (message.getText().startsWith("/inline"))
            {
                markup = new InlineKeyboardMarkup();
                final List<List<InlineKeyboardButton>> keyboard = ((InlineKeyboardMarkup) markup).getKeyboard();
                for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
                {
                    if (keyboard.isEmpty() || (keyboard.get(keyboard.size() - 1).size() >= 3))
                    {
                        keyboard.add(new ArrayList<>());
                    }
                    keyboard.get(keyboard.size() - 1).add(new InlineKeyboardButton().setText(" Button name #" + (i + 1)).setCallbackData("Button callback " + (i + 1)));
                }
            }
            else if (message.getText().startsWith("/keyboard"))
            {
                markup = new ReplyKeyboardMarkup();
                final List<KeyboardRow> keyboard = ((ReplyKeyboardMarkup) markup).getKeyboard();
                for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
                {
                    if (keyboard.isEmpty() || (keyboard.get(keyboard.size() - 1).size() >= 3))
                    {
                        keyboard.add(new KeyboardRow());
                    }
                    keyboard.get(keyboard.size() - 1).add(new KeyboardButton().setText(" Button #" + (i + 1)));
                }
            }
            final SendMessage msg = new SendMessage();
            msg.setChatId(Long.toString(message.getChat().getId()));
            msg.setText("Your text here");
            msg.setReplyToMessageId(message.getMessageId());
            msg.setReplyMarkup(markup);
            try
            {
                execute(msg);
            }
            catch (TelegramApiException e)
            {
                LOGGER.warn("Failed to execute SendMessage: ", e);
            }
        }
        else if (update.hasCallbackQuery())
        {
            final AnswerCallbackQuery answer = new AnswerCallbackQuery();
            answer.setCallbackQueryId(update.getCallbackQuery().getId());
            answer.setText("You've clicked at the button: " + update.getCallbackQuery().getData());
            answer.setShowAlert(true);
            try
            {
                execute(answer);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                LOGGER.warn("Failed to execute AnswerCallbackQuery: ", e);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String getBotUsername()
    {
        return _username;
    }

    @Override
    public String getBotToken()
    {
        return _token;
    }
}
```